# Problem deploying Hololens app to emulator from Visual studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio-2019, hololens, mrtk, hololens-emulator

I am building a simple **hololens app** using **MRTK PalmUpHandMenu**, I am able to build the app in unity but not able to deploy on hololens Emulator from visual studio. The app is playing in game mode of unity.

I am using the following tools.

- Visual Studio 2019
- unity 2019.2.21f1
- Windows SDK 10.1.18362.1
- Hololens 2 emulator 10.1.18362.1053
- mixed reality toolkit 2.3.0
- Windows 10 pro

Here are my unity build configuration

[image: Build Setting]

[image: Player Setting]

Here are my Visual Studio configuration

[image: vs deployment configuration]

Here are my Debug logs from the visual studio.

```
The thread 0x14dc has exited with code 0 (0x0).
'Hololens 2.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\shlwapi_onecore.dll'
CreateDirectory 'C:/Data' failed: Operation has failed with error 0xb7: Cannot create a file when that file already exists.
 (current dir: C:/Data/Users/DefaultAccount/AppData/Local/DevelopmentFiles/Template3DVS.Debug_Win32.Salman/Data)
Logging to C:/Data/Users/Visitor0/AppData/Local/Packages/Template3D_pzq3xp76mxafg/TempState/UnityPlayer.log
[0.799436 / 0.830282] - Initializing Unity runtime
Loading native plugins
  Loading AudioPluginMsHRTF.dll
Module information:
 Built with Compiler Ver '191627012'
 Built from '2019.2/staging' branch
 Version is '2019.2.21f1 (9d528d026557)'
 Debug build
 Application type 'D3D'
Exception thrown at 0x77C33E02 in Hololens 2.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: Cn::XH at memory location 0x021CE6F4.
onecoreuap\windows\moderncore\inputv2\inputhost\components\cursor\client\cursorclient.cpp(44)\InputHost.dll!74422413: (caller: 7442258C) ReturnHr(1) tid(1110) 87B20809 onecoreuap\windows\moderncore\inputv2\inputhost\components\cursor\client\cursorclient.cpp(76)\InputHost.dll!744225A3: (caller: 743E034D) ReturnHr(2) tid(1110) 87B20809  OS 'Windows 10 (10.0.18362) 64bit'
[0.001811 / 3.483454] - AppCallbacks::SetCoreWindowEvents
PlayerConnection initialized from C:/Data/Users/DefaultAccount/AppData/Local/DevelopmentFiles/Template3DVS.Debug_Win32.Salman/Data (debug = 0)
'Hololens 2.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ResourcePolicyClient.dll'
PlayerConnection initialized network socket : 0.0.0.0 55403
Multi-casting "[IP] 192.168.233.185 [Port] 55403 [Flags] 2 [Guid] 4154280957 [EditorId] 0 [Version] 1048832 [Id] UWPPlayerX86(HOLOLENS-PURI8R) [Debug] 0 [PackageName] Template3D_pzq3xp76mxafg" to [225.0.0.222:54997]...
Started listening to [0.0.0.0:55403]
Exception thrown at 0x77C33E02 in Hololens 2.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: _com_error at memory location 0x021C82A0.
Exception thrown at 0x77C33E02 in Hololens 2.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: _com_error at memory location 0x021C82D0.
PlayerConnection already initialized - listening to [0.0.0.0:55403]
'Hololens 2.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dxilconv.dll'
[5.860794 / 6.849624] - Initialize
'Hololens 2.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\system32\HostDriverStore\FileRepository\iigd_dch.inf_amd64_38bfcb542ef4272e\igdinfo32.dll'
'Hololens 2.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\system32\HostDriverStore\FileRepository\iigd_dch.inf_amd64_38bfcb542ef4272e\igd12dxva32.dll'
'Hololens 2.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\system32\HostDriverStore\FileRepository\iigd_dch.inf_amd64_38bfcb542ef4272e\igdgmm32.dll'
'Hololens 2.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\system32\HostDriverStore\FileRepository\iigd_dch.inf_amd64_38bfcb542ef4272e\igd12umd32.dll'
The thread 0x1418 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
[4.616554 / 8.100700] - AppCallbacks::InitializeD3DWindow
The thread 0x1060 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
[XR] Discovering subsystems at path C:/Data/Users/DefaultAccount/AppData/Local/DevelopmentFiles/Template3DVS.Debug_Win32.Salman/Data/UnitySubsystems
GfxDevice: creating device client; threaded=1
[8.129256 / 8.129256] - OnActivated event.
[0.069105 / 8.198361] - OnCoreWindowSizeChanged event (0.00, 0.00, 853.00, 480.00), m_Initialized=False.
[0.001614 / 8.199975] - OnVisibilityChanged event - Visible.
[0.043964 / 8.243939] - OnWindowActivated event - CodeActivated.
Successfully created d3d11 device with debug flag.
Direct3D:
    Version:  Direct3D 11.0 [level 11.1]
    Renderer: Microsoft Virtual Render Driver (ID=0x5921)
    Vendor:   (null)
    VRAM:     3967 MB
Initialize engine version: 2019.2.21f1 (9d528d026557)
[AudioManager] InitNormal(tryDeviceDefaults = false, preferredOutputType = FMOD_OUTPUTTYPE_AUTODETECT) attempt with hardAudioDisable: false
[AudioManager] Setting output to FMOD_OUTPUTTYPE_AUTODETECT
[4.750430 / 12.994369] - OnCoreWindowSizeChanged event (0.00, 0.00, 853.00, 480.00), m_Initialized=False.
[AudioManager] InitNormal succeeded with output "FMOD_OUTPUTTYPE_WASAPI". Driver name is "Speakers (Null Audio Driver)". Speaker mode is "FMOD_SPEAKERMODE_STEREO"
The thread 0x1068 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x142c has exited with code 0 (0x0).
onecoreuap\xbox\devices\api\winrt\pnpapiwrapper.cpp(385)\Windows.Gaming.Input.dll!661DF669: (caller: 661E24EF) ReturnHr(1) tid(5a4) 8685C003 [0.000928 / 16.034495] - AppCallbacks::SetupInputEvents
onecoreuap\drivers\mobilepc\sensors\convergence\common\pnpmanager\pnpmanager.cpp(260)\Windows.Devices.Sensors.dll!66152250: (caller: 66152320) Exception(1) tid(1110) 80070490 Element not found.
Exception thrown at 0x77C33E02 in Hololens 2.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: wil::ResultException at memory location 0x021CDA88.
Exception thrown at 0x77C33E02 in Hololens 2.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: [rethrow] at memory location 0x00000000.
Exception thrown at 0x77C33E02 (KernelBase.dll) in Hololens 2.exe: WinRT originate error - 0x80070490 : 'Element not found.'.
The thread 0x1230 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
onecoreuap\shell\twinapi\windowingenvironment\lib\displayregion.cpp(203)\twinapi.appcore.dll!76A12A30: (caller: 76AC74BD) ReturnHr(1) tid(1110) 80070490 Element not found.
onecoreuap\drivers\mobilepc\sensors\convergence\api\winrt\public\internal\simpleorientation.cpp(127)\Windows.Devices.Sensors.dll!6614B9F3: (caller: 661425E8) Exception(2) tid(1110) 80070490 Element not found.
Exception thrown at 0x77C33E02 in Hololens 2.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: wil::ResultException at memory location 0x021CDD28.
Exception thrown at 0x77C33E02 in Hololens 2.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: [rethrow] at memory location 0x00000000.
onecoreuap\drivers\mobilepc\sensors\convergence\api\winrt\public\internal\sensorserver.cpp(68)\Windows.Devices.Sensors.dll!6613E1CB: (caller: 6613B5FA) ReturnHr(1) tid(1110) 80070490 Element not found.
onecoreuap\drivers\mobilepc\sensors\convergence\api\winrt\public\lib\simpleorientationsensor.cpp(160)\Windows.Devices.Sensors.dll!6612BAA6: (caller: 66129763) ReturnHr(2) tid(1110) 80070490 Element not found.
[0.498514 / 16.533405] - AppCallbacks::SetupOrientationSensorEvents
[1.605693 / 17.290356] - AppCallbacks::Load
[4.326316 / 17.320685] - Starting first scene loading
The following GlobalManagers were stripped from the build (Either because they're not used or not supported on this platform):
  ClusterInputManager
[0.126562 / 17.447248] - OnCoreWindowSizeChanged event (0.00, 0.00, 1440.00, 936.00), m_Initialized=True.
Created eye textures with a "texture array" layout.  The "single-pass instancing" stereo mode will be used.

[4.957320 / 22.404567] - Finishing first scene loading
[0.019790 / 22.424357] - First level loaded
[0.018120 / 22.442477] - PerformUpdateAndRender started
Windows Mixed Reality spatial locatability state changed to Active.

(Filename: C:\buildslave\unity\build\Modules/VR/HoloLens/HoloLensWorldManager.cpp Line: 324)

End showing splash screen.
Exception thrown at 0x77C33E02 in Hololens 2.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: Cn::XH at memory location 0x0797FA54.
onecoreuap\windows\moderncore\inputv2\inputhost\components\devicewatcher\lib\inputdevicewatcher.cpp(100)\InputHost.dll!7442FA78: (caller: 670B4732) LogHr(1) tid(15f4) 87B20809 [10.309595 / 32.752072] - OnWindowActivated event - Deactivated.
[0.017715 / 32.769787] - OnVisibilityChanged event - Hidden.
[1.026859 / 33.796646] - OnSuspending event.
Trimming D3D resources.
UnloadTime: 6.003500 ms
The thread 0x119c has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x1180 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0xe60 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0xb8c has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x15b8 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0xc98 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x111c has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x1118 has exited with code 1 (0x1).
The thread 0x1110 has exited with code 1 (0x1).
The thread 0x15f4 has exited with code 1 (0x1).
The thread 0x165c has exited with code 1 (0x1).
The thread 0x1178 has exited with code 1 (0x1).
The thread 0x147c has exited with code 1 (0x1).
The thread 0x1198 has exited with code 1 (0x1).
The thread 0x12d0 has exited with code 1 (0x1).
The thread 0x5a4 has exited with code 1 (0x1).
The thread 0xae8 has exited with code 1 (0x1).
The thread 0xce8 has exited with code 1 (0x1).
The thread 0x16d4 has exited with code 1 (0x1).
The thread 0x1498 has exited with code 1 (0x1).
The thread 0xcfc has exited with code 1 (0x1).
The thread 0x155c has exited with code 1 (0x1).
The thread 0x5a8 has exited with code 1 (0x1).
The thread 0xcac has exited with code 1 (0x1).
The thread 0x8d0 has exited with code 1 (0x1).
The thread 0x16c4 has exited with code 1 (0x1).
The thread 0x149c has exited with code 1 (0x1).
The thread 0xe74 has exited with code 1 (0x1).
The thread 0x1108 has exited with code 1 (0x1).
The thread 0xf38 has exited with code 1 (0x1).
The thread 0x1114 has exited with code 1 (0x1).
The thread 0x17ac has exited with code 1 (0x1).
The thread 0xdf8 has exited with code 1 (0x1).
The thread 0x998 has exited with code 1 (0x1).
The thread 0x840 has exited with code 1 (0x1).
The thread 0xa3c has exited with code 1 (0x1).
The thread 0x374 has exited with code 1 (0x1).
The thread 0x638 has exited with code 1 (0x1).
The thread 0x14d4 has exited with code 1 (0x1).
The thread 0x1170 has exited with code 1 (0x1).
The thread 0x870 has exited with code 1 (0x1).
The thread 0xe9c has exited with code 1 (0x1).
The thread 0x12b0 has exited with code 1 (0x1).
The thread 0xd74 has exited with code 1 (0x1).
The thread 0x1220 has exited with code 1 (0x1).
The thread 0x1314 has exited with code 1 (0x1).
The thread 0x644 has exited with code 1 (0x1).
The thread 0x9b8 has exited with code 1 (0x1).
The thread 0x6fc has exited with code 1 (0x1).
The thread 0xe68 has exited with code 1 (0x1).
The thread 0x12a8 has exited with code 1 (0x1).
The thread 0xcec has exited with code 1 (0x1).
The thread 0xcf8 has exited with code 1 (0x1).
The program '[6036] Hololens 2.exe' has exited with code 1 (0x1).
```

Is my configuration correct or Is there any issue with the compatibility of the version of the tools. Any help is appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: As a test, please add the Windows Mixed Reality app templates to Visual Studio by going to Extensions -> Manage Extensions and searching for "Mixed Reality".  Once the templates are installed, create a new Holographic DirectX 11 project (no need to add any code - just use the default template) and build and run it on the emulator.  Do you see the same behavior, or do you see a spinning cube on the screen?  This will help narrow down if it's an issue with your configuration or an issue with Unity.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried with DirectX 11 project. On running it on emulator initially the spinning ball with the cube screen appears then Hololens Launch screen appears. The behaviour is same as unity.

Comment: When you say "the HoloLens launch screen appears", do you mean the pins panel (with the application tiles) or do you see the Windows logo (the white flag with spinning dots beneath it)?  If you bring up the emulator tools window (click ">>" on the emulator toolbar) and go to the "Diagnostics" tab, what does it say for "Virtual GPU"?

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same problem, also the app deployed to the emulator but nothing happens after that, then the app exited with code (1).
I thought my problem is because I am using Windows 10 pro on bootcamp under a Mac machine, are you running on a Windows machine or a Mac machine?

Comment: I am running this app on Windows 10 Pro.

Comment: I mean what is your Laptop? is it Surface or Dell, because mine is MAC and I am facing the same problem exactly as you described, first the spinning balls with the windows 4-cube sign appears then the Hololens Launch screen appears, then nothing. First I thought this is because I am running it on MAC. Someone told me may be the retaina display doesn't match the emulator requirements for the monitor. Have you checked that your monitor matches the emulator requirements.